# añadir formulario al presionar un botón?

Tags: php, javascript, html

```
<form action="page.php" method="post">
    <div>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="email">email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" />
    </div>
   <div class="button">
        <button type="button">add</button>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="msg">Message:</label>
        <textarea id="msg"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="button">
        <button type="submit">Send your message</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola, me gustaria saber como puedo hacer que cuando presione el boton add me añada otro campo "email".

Tambien me gustaria que los campos extras se pudieran eliminar con el boton del.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Si usas la librería jQuery de javaScript lo podrías hacer de esta sencilla forma:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add_email").click(function(){
        var contador = $("input[type='email']").length;

        $(this).before('<div><label for="email_'+ contador +'">email:</label><input type="email" id="email_'+ contador +'" name="email[]"/><button type="button" class="delete_email">Del</button></div>');
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.delete_email', function(){
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="page.php" method="post">
    <div>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="email">email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email[]"/>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
        <button type="button" id="add_email">add</button>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="msg">Message:</label>
        <textarea id="msg"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="button">
        <button type="submit">Send your message</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**EXPLICACIÓN:**

Tu PHP recibe los datos que envíes utilizando los atributos `name` de los campos del formulario, como vas a tener varios email (no se sabe exactamente cuantos van a ser) puedes volver ese atributo un `array` de la siguiente manera `name="email[]"`, así con cada email que ingreses se irá ingresando al array y podrás recibirlos en PHP sin ningún problema.

Comment: hola, gracias por la respuesta, pero el id de cada campo no deberia ser unico?

Comment: Oh claro, podemos usar un contador para controlar eso, déjame te edito para que veas !

Comment: @nakhqoy he editado la respuesta !

Comment: ya veo, pero me queda una ultima duda, como obtengo el dato en php si el id es aleatorio y no se cuantos campos hay?

Comment: @nakhqoy te he editado la respuesta con la edición a tu pregunta (el botón eliminar), ahora te pregunto: vas a enviar los datos a php por medio de ajax o vas a usar el método convencional ?

Comment: metodo combencional

Comment: @nakhqoy te volví a editar la respuesta con una breve explicación de como enviar los datos a php, debes terminar de colocar los atributos name al resto de elementos (input, select, etc)

Answer (score 1):

```js
    var nextinput = 0;
    function AgregarCampos(){
    nextinput++;
    campo = '<li id="rut'+nextinput+'">Campo:<input type="email" size="20" id="campo' + nextinput + '"&nbsp; name="campo' + nextinput + '"&nbsp; /></li>';
    $("#campos").append(campo);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button">
                <a href="#" onclick="AgregarCampos();">Agregar Campos</a>
            </div>
    <div id="campos">
```

con javascript al presionar el boton se activa la funcion agregarCampos y te lo va agregando

Comment: hola, gracias por la respuesta, pero como obtengo el dato en php si el id es aleatorio y no se cuantos campos hay?

Comment: simple, email es un arreglo debes hacer un for en PHP